# how to combine two foreache´s

Tags: php, foreach

hey there i got a litte problem with my script...
this is the first part:

```
$imagesPerLine = array(1=>2, 2=>3); $default = 4;

$lines = array(1, 2, 3);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
  if (!isset($imagesPerLine[$line])) {
    $imagesPerLine[$line] = $default;
  }
  echo "<tr>\n";
  for ($i = 1; $i <= $imagesPerLine[$line]; $i++) {
    echo "<td>[img]</td>\n";
  }
  echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

as a result i get the following:

```
 <tr>
   <td>[img]</td>
   <td>[img]</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>[img]</td>
   <td>[img]</td>
   <td>[img]</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>[img]</td>
   <td>[img]</td>
   <td>[img]</td>
   <td>[img]</td>
 </tr>
```

but instead of "[img]" i want it to display:

```
function getTransactionStatusImagePath($transactionId)
{
$states = array('schwarz', 'rot', 'blau');

$path = '';

foreach ($states as $state) {
  $testPath = sprintf('transactions/Ordner%s/%s.png', $transactionId, $state);

    if (file_exists($testPath)) {
      $path = $testPath;
      break;
    }
}
return $path;
}

$transactionIds = range(1,9);

foreach ($transactionIds as $transactionId) :

if (($transactionId % $imagesPerLine) == 1)
  echo "<tr>\n";

$path = getTransactionStatusImagePath($transactionId);

$imageHtml = ('' !== $path)
    ? '<img src="' . $path . '" />'
    : '<img name="nummer.' . $transactionId . '" src="inventory_images/8.jpg"  onclick="changecolor(this)" />' ;

echo "<td>$imageHtml</td>\n";

if (! ($transactionId % $imagesPerLine))
  echo "</tr>\n";

endforeach;
```

so it should be like this:

```
 <tr>
   <td><img name="nummer.1" src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" /></td>
   <td><img name="nummer.1" src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><img name="nummer.1" src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" /></td>
   <td><img name="nummer.1" src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" /></td>
   <td><img name="nummer.1" src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><img name="nummer.1" src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" /></td>
   <td><img name="nummer.1" src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" /></td>
   <td><img name="nummer.1" src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" /></td>
   <td><img name="nummer.1" src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" /></td>
 </tr>
```

how should i combine these two foreache´s to reach my aim?
greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is being caused by you echoing your HTML as it is generated, rather than constructing it as a complete string, then echoing that.  It gets much easier if you do something like:

```
$imagesPerLine = array(1=>2, 2=>3); $default = 4;
$lines = array(1, 2, 3);
$html="";
foreach ($lines as $line) {
  if (!isset($imagesPerLine[$line])) {
    $imagesPerLine[$line] = $default;
  }
  $html.= "<tr>";
  for ($i = 1; $i <= $imagesPerLine[$line]; $i++) {
   $html.=sprintf("<td>%s</td>",function_to_generate_image_detail($imagesPerLine[$line]));
  }
  $html.="</tr>";

}
 echo $html;
```

It is hard to determine exactly how you want to generate your image text but, obviously, your function will need to return only

```
<img name="nummer.1" src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" />
```

or whatever else you need.  You seem able to create this bit, so I'll leave that to you.

Note that your code contains other errors, including:

```
if (($transactionId % $imagesPerLine) == 1)
```

where you are using an array as the denominator in a division.  Unwise indeed.  Write the function as I suggested and you will be a happy chap.  Or chapess.